# Check if .NET LDAP Bind was successfull

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, ldap-query

Current Issue:
When trying to execute a search on an LDAP Connection in .NET, the server response is that a "*successfull bind*" has to be made beforehand, which in my prior experience with LDAP Error messages I honestly dont buy.

The code for the search is as follows:

```
var req = new SearchRequest("dc=test,dc=intern", "(&(sAMAccountName=*test*))", SubTree, new string[1] { "cn" });

uSearchResults = (SearchResponse)uEntry.SendRequest(req).Entries;

dblSearchResultsCount = uSearchResults.Count;
```

The code for the bind is the following:

```
 try
    {
        connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(LdapHost, LdapPort));

        connection.AuthType = 2;
        connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 2;
        connection.Credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(strUsername, strPassword);
        connection.Bind();

        LogEvent("Bind", 0, "Bind most likely successfull, no exception was thrown");
    }
    catch (Global.System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException ServerEx2)
    {
        //Logging Code
        return false;
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        //Logging Code
        return false;
    }
    catch (LdapException ex)
    {
       //Logging Code
       return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogEvent("Bind", 0, ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see, I am catching every error known to man in the bind process, which as far as I know is the only way to check if the bind worked or not. The credentials, host and port are also verified to be correct.

**The connection variable has no properties or functions known to me to check if a bind was successfull. The only measure I can take if the bind worked is to check if any errors occured along the way.**

**How can I check in the `connection` variable that is of the type `LdapConnection` if the bind was actually successfull?**

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is nothing to try though. The connection variable does not have any functions or properties with which to read the bind state, and except for looking for exceptions upon binding I do not know any other way to check, hence why I'm asking

Comment: Try something like:
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    var serverId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(connection.SessionOptions.HostName);

    var conn = new LdapConnection(serverId, credentials);
    try
    {
        conn.Bind();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         Log("Bind", 0, Exception.Message);
    }

Answer (score 1):

The [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.DirectoryServices.Protocols/src/System/DirectoryServices/Protocols/ldap/LdapConnection.cs) shows that it keeps a `_bounded` boolean variable, but does not expose it. So you can't check it.

But the [code for binding](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.DirectoryServices.Protocols/src/System/DirectoryServices/Protocols/ldap/LdapConnection.cs#L1053) does show that it will throw an exception if *anything* goes wrong. So if no exception is thrown when you call `Bind()`, you know the bind was successful.